# Xmlstarlet unable to change value in xml file using --update

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I am trying to change the child element value for version in the below app-manifest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fabricapp xmlns="XXXXXXXX">
<components>
<component type="native">
  <metadata>
    <name>Biofrost Engineering Setting</name>
    <description>aaaaa</description>
    <version>v1</version>
    <licenseable>N</licenseable>
    <networktype>D</networktype>
  </metadata>
```

This is the command i use :

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace --update //fabricapp/components/component/metadata[name="Biofrost Engineering Setting"]/version -v 4 app-manifest.xml
```

But still there is no change in the xml file. Can someone please help in letting me know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Your XPath doesn't account for the default namespace in your XML.  See duplicate link for details.

Comment: Thanks you very much @kjhughes . I am new to xml parsing hence your guidance was really helpful.